# Hover effect issue on Safari 10.0

Tags: javascript, css, safari, hover, transform

There is an issue with the hover effect that only appears on **Safari 10.0**.

The web is this:
[Manu Caballero](https://manu-caballero.es)

What is happening is that the effect is working radomly, or not working at all:
[image: Hover effect doesn't working]
To see it working, you can use Chrome or Firefox.

The most strange thing is that, on Safari 10.0, if I try to use the inspector, the hover effect works...
[image]

On Safari 10.1 and other common browsers like Chrome, Firefox... is working perfectly.

Comment: please share the code.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Santhoshkumar. It's a wordpress template. I put the link to the web so, that way, you can inspect. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, Thanks @anfuca...

Answer (score 6):

Looking at this site it appears to be using jQuery 1.12.4 and jQuery Migrate 1.4.1 - this is adequate if you need to support IE6 but not something I'd expect to be sufficient for Safari 10 (released after these legacy libraries).

On top of this you appear to be using Isotope 3.0.1, which is also about a year out of date.

So, first I'd recommend:

- Upgrading to a current version of jQuery and dropping Migrate - IE6 is dead and IE8 is marginal.
- Upgrade Isotope to the current version.

In particular check their [issue logs](https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues) for similar issues before raising them on here.

If the problem persists after that then you may have an issue specific to your implementation. Isolate the code in a snippet in your question - it's much easier for us to help you with one specific issue without reverse engineering your entire site.

Comment: Thanks @Keith. I'll check your recommendations tomorrow and I wish I can tell you some advance.

Answer (score 3):

Delete this code https://yadi.sk/d/YmKdx2Rd3M2Fcj and your effect will be work fine
and look this video https://www.screenmailer.com/v/EEa7t15khxyLE9s

Comment: Very interesting @grinmax ! I've taken a look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d and seems like Safari is supporting `transform-2d` from `10.1`. 
With your solution, the effect will not be exactly the same that is already now working in most browsers.
Of course is an important advance! I'm still pending to try what @Keith suggested me, to see if some change into javascript can fix the issue... Let's see!

Comment: @Anfuca i see that safari supporting 2d beginning with 3.2 version )) https://yadi.sk/d/LzDMle813M4Fky